# Error- org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project ABC: Exception in provider: java/sql/Date: java.sql.Date

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

**Error 1** - org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project ABC: Exception in provider: java/sql/Date: java.sql.Date

**Error 2** - 4144777 [pool-1-thread-1 for channel id=9] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - Couldn't find template in cache for "Extent.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.

Test Cases are running and testing report is generated perfectly, in my local. But when I run them in Jenkins I am getting above errors.
Here the POM file.

```
     <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        </properties>

       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta</version>
        </plugin>

       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.28</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

How can I solve this issue.
Need anyother information from my side please let me know.

Comment: You are using ancient old plugin versions (maven-surefire-plugin; https://maven.apache.org/plugins/), also all the dependencies are ancient old... You should check to upgrade the dependencies to the version which work with JDK8...

Comment: If you are using `java.sql.Date`, you should also upgrade to `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). `java.sql.Date` was a true hack on top of the already problematic `java.util.Date`. Both have been outdated for 10 years now.

Comment: Yes I updated the maven version and it resolved my issue. @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated maven version and it resolved both the issue

```
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
```

Now my test cases are running perfectly in local as well as in Jenkins both.

Comment: Why even that old? Upgrade to most recent version 3.2.5 ...